# event name to track user visits in Google analytics 4 measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

Previously were using universal tracking to track user visits to Google Analytics using python script from the backend application.

Now migrating to Google Analytics 4 and using the Measurement Protocol to send events to record in Google Analytics

[Events list reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference/events) Lists a few events and required parameters, however, most of them look like e-commerce events. However, I want to record visits to my website.

How should the event name, if it has to be from the predefined list? Or how can I create event names?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this hit builder: https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/event-builder/

You can choose `Custom` as `event_category`, then you can use `page_view` as `event_name`.